# How can I enumerate the list of privileges granted to an Oracle role?

Tags: oracle, plsql, roles

I have a homegrown Oracle role that was created long ago:

```
create role MyRole;
```

It's been granted the ability to select, insert, update, and delete from some tables and views.

```
grant select on sometable to MyRole;
grant insert on sometable to MyRole;
grant select on someothertable to MyRole;
-- etc.
```

How can I now enumerate the specific list of privileges that were granted to the role?  I am interested in discovering the specific tables and the rights this role has with respect to each table.  How can I recover this information?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can simply search from data dictionary `ROLE_TAB_PRIVS`. And do like this

> SELECT * FROM ROLE_TAB_PRIVS WHERE ROLE = 'MyRole';

Answer (score 5):

this works well:

```
SELECT DBA_TAB_PRIVS.GRANTEE, TABLE_NAME, PRIVILEGE,DBA_ROLE_PRIVS.GRANTEE
FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS, DBA_ROLE_PRIVS
WHERE DBA_TAB_PRIVS.GRANTEE = DBA_ROLE_PRIVS.GRANTED_ROLE
AND DBA_TAB_PRIVS.GRANTEE='<ENTER GROUP ROLE HERE>'
AND DBA_ROLE_PRIVS.GRANTEE = '<ENTER ROLE HERE>'
ORDER BY DBA_ROLE_PRIVS.GRANTEE
```